# Работает ли Битрикс на nginx?

Tags: битрикс

Сейчас устаналиваю 1С Битрикс Управление сайтом. Указано минимальное требование Apache 1.3. У меня уставновлен nginx. Будет ли работать Битрикс на nginx? Если нет, то как можно установить apache не удаляла nginx? Спасибо

Comment: 1) Официально нет, неофициально может и получится запустить; 2) Просто взять и установить, apache и nginx не конфликтуют друг с другом никак (кроме занимаемых портов, но изменить их не проблема)

Comment: только на nginx - может работать. Но очень много каких-то переподвывертов приходится либо долго гуглить и "пробовать" приходится. У вас то не ахти какой высоконагруженный проект? Да? Ставьте и Apache - буден сон у вас крепче)

Answer (score 0):

Битрикс отлично работает на связке Apache+nginx (в рамках виртуальной машины или без) или отдельно на apache.
Nginx можно настроить для работы с Битрикс.

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/780663)